# The google translate widget has changed and seems to be broken. Has anyone been able to come up with a fix?

Tags: google-translate

As of 2023 the Google Translate Widget seems to have changed and be slightly broken also.

Those of us who hide the actual widget and interact with it via our own custom interfaces will really notice the breakage as, due to the removal of certain class names on the `iframe` (and other interface elements) the styles to hide those elements, and the javascript to interact with them will no longer work correctly.

The change in class names is easy to fix by targeting the elements in other ways, but sadly the widget also appears to have a bug resulting in this error after trying to change the language from one non-original language to another:

```
TypeError: a is not an Object. (evaluating '"textContent"in a')
```

Has anyone else managed to come up with a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work around the errors for now. The key is not to interact with the `iframe` at all. Instead, work with the `.goog-te-combo` element:

```
const select = document.querySelector('#google_translate_element .goog-te-combo')
select.value = new_language_code
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))

if (new_language_code === original_language_code) {
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
}
```

Basically when setting a new language code you just need to update the select and trigger `change`, however if you're setting the language back to the original page language that you'd defined in your google translate setup script then you need to trigger a second `change` event because the widget removes the original language from the select and replaces it with an extra blank value that says 'Select Language' or something to that effect. If you don't do this extra event then the next language you attempt to select won't take effect.